# change html form element placeholder with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help changing the `placeholder` value on a input field with javascript, preferably JQuery.

`<input id="someinput" value="" placeholder="Change This With JS" type="text">`

Comment: changing how? Like change the default value of the placeholder using jQuery? Change the functionality of the placeholder by using jQuery (polyfill)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**demo** like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qcNFF/ ?

Good read: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

**code**

```
$(function() {
    alert(' Before change => ' + $('#someinput').prop('placeholder'));
    $('#someinput').prop('placeholder', "text changed- hulk");
    alert(' After change => ' + $('#someinput').prop('placeholder'));
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a quick demo for you:

the fiddle code
http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/H7MG7/

just use jquery's .attr() method to changed the string.